# Create hash from variables in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I want to end up with an array of hashes.

I am starting with an array of codes:

```
@codes = ['123', '456', '789']
```

I take each of those codes and hit an API with them and it returns values that I parse into variables in a loop, like so:

```
@codes.each do |x|
  @y = x.get_some_data
  @brand = @y[brand]
  @size = @y[size]
end
```

Then I want to put this data into an array of hashes

```
merged_array = []
final_hash = @codes.map{|code| {:code => code, :brand=> @brand, :size=> @size}
merged_array << final_hash
```

And in a perfect world, end up with hashes that look like this in the `merged_array`:

```
 {:code => '123', :brand=> 'nike', :size=> 8 }
 {:code => '456', :brand=> 'adidas', :size=> 4 }
 {:code => '789', :brand=> 'converse', :size=> 10 }
```

But when I run my script it maps the codes right, but overwrites the `@brand`, `@size` variables and just returns the values of the last loop.

Not sure how to get all my variables into the hashes?

Comment: instead of the `codes.each` section just put all this logic directly in the `map` method also probably no need for instance variables since you will just discard this data anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code example, the variables are all declared as being instance variables, because they're prefixed with `@`.

However, the variables within the loop are simply working/temporary variables, not instance variables. Additionally, `x.get_some_data` is probably not working, since `x` is just the loop variable and contains `456`, `abc`, etc., and not an object with the desired method. Thus, the following code should produce your desired result:

```
def get_data(codes)
  result = []
  codes.each do |code|
    y = get_some_data(code)
    result << {
      code: code,
      brand: y['brand'],
      size: y['size']
    }
  end
  result
end
```

This is a very verbose example; you can put the whole logic in `map`, if the return value of `get_some_data` permits it.

A more elegant version would utilize [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) (the `Array` class includes `Enumereable`):

```
def get_data(codes)
  codes.each_with_object([]) do |code, result|
    y = get_some_data(code)
    result << {
      code: code,
      brand: y['brand'],
      size: y['size']
    }
  end
end
```

Thanks,  Cary Swoveland, for pointing this out!

Comment: arghhhhh.. the answer was really your very first line.. instance vs. temp variables.. I changed them to the method/temp variables and everything is working fine now.. wow.. easy fix but I just didn't see it!! thanks so much

Comment: A small suggestion: instead of `result = []` at the beginning and `result` at the end, `codes.each_with_object([]) { |code, result|...`.

Comment: Good idea, @CarySwoveland, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work

```
@codes.map{|code| {:code => code, :brand => code.get_some_data['brand'], code.get_some_data['size']}}
```

But, I'm really not sure what **String.get_some_data** will give you. Eg:- `'123'.get_some_data['brand']`